# Как вставить значения переменных в базу данных MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Не получается **вставить** значения переменных в таблицу базы данных **MYSQL**. Переменные отправляю через форму в обработчик. Все переменные в обработчик приходят.(проверял), а вот **записать** значения переменных в таблицу не получается. Пишу через функцию **mysql_query** **INSERT INTO**. Вроде код нормальный.

Код обработчика такой:

```
<?php

if (isset($raion) && isset($tip) && isset($cat) && isset($material) && isset($author) && isset($street) && isset($dom) && isset($s_ob) && isset($s_gil) && isset($s_kuh) && isset($stage) && isset($stage_st) && isset($text) && isset($price) && isset($meta_d) && isset($meta_k) && isset($description) && isset($view) && isset($date) && isset($mini_img) && isset($title)) {
    $result_add = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (raion, tip, cat, material, author, street, dom, s_ob, s_gil, s_kuh, stage, stage_st, text, price, meta_d, meta_k, description, view, date, mini_img, title) VALUES ('$raion', '$tip', '$cat', '$material', '$author', '$street', '$home', '$s_ob', '$s_gil', '$s_kuh', '$stage', '$stage_st', '$text', '$price', '$meta_d', '$meta_k', '$description', '$view', '$date', '$mini_img', '$title')");

    if ($result_add == 'true') {
        echo "<p>Успешно добавлено в базу</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Не добавлено в базу</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Вы зполнили не все поля!!!</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, как я сам не догадался, просто была ошибка в том, что было неправильно задано имя одной из ячеек таблицы куда вставляются данные.

Comment: Ну тогда принимайте! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну раз не вставляется в базу, значит должна быть ошибка. Сделайте `mysql_error()` и `mysql_errno()` , там где у вас написано "Не добавлено в базу"